# How to limit the maximum value of a numeric field in a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, limit, django-validation

Django has various numeric fields available for use in models, e.g. [DecimalField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) and [PositiveIntegerField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield). Although the former can be restricted to the number of decimal places stored and the overall number of characters stored, is there any way to restrict it to storing *only* numbers within a certain range, e.g. 0.0-5.0?

Failing that, is there any way to restrict a PositiveIntegerField to only store, for instance, numbers up to 50?

***Update: now that Bug 6845 [has been closed](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6845#comment:71), this StackOverflow question may be moot.***

Comment: You could create a pre-save signal: [http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I also want the restriction to be applied in Django's admin. For getting that, at least, the documentation has this to say: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin

Comment: Actually, pre-1.0 Django seems to have had a really elegant solution: http://www.cotellese.net/2007/12/11/adding-model-field-validation-to-the-django-admin-page/ . I wonder if there's an equally elegant way of doing this in the svn release of Django.

Comment: I'm disappointed to learn that there *doesn't* seem to be an elegant way to do this with the current Django svn. See this discussion thread for more details: http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/7f23e90d9d3aedd4

Comment: Use validators on the model, and the validation will work in the admin interface and in ModelForms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#built-in-validators

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You could also create a custom model field type - see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#howto-custom-model-fields

In this case, you could 'inherit' from the built-in IntegerField and override its validation logic.

The more I think about this, I realize how useful this would be for many Django apps. Perhaps a IntegerRangeField type could be submitted as a patch for the Django devs to consider adding to trunk.

This is working for me:

```
from django.db import models

class IntegerRangeField(models.IntegerField):
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, min_value=None, max_value=None, **kwargs):
        self.min_value, self.max_value = min_value, max_value
        models.IntegerField.__init__(self, verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'min_value': self.min_value, 'max_value':self.max_value}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(IntegerRangeField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

Then in your model class, you would use it like this (field being the module where you put the above code):

```
size = fields.IntegerRangeField(min_value=1, max_value=50)
```

OR for a range of negative and positive (like an oscillator range):

```
size = fields.IntegerRangeField(min_value=-100, max_value=100)
```

What would be really cool is if it could be called with the range operator like this:

```
size = fields.IntegerRangeField(range(1, 50))
```

But, that would require a lot more code since since you can specify a 'skip' parameter - range(1, 50, 2) - Interesting idea though...

Comment: This works but when in the model's clean method, the value of the integer is always None which makes it so I cannot provide any additional cleaning to it.  Any idea why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: You can enhance your custom field by adding`MinValueValidator(min_value) and MaxValueValidator(max_value)` before calling `super().__init__ ...` (snippet: https://gist.github.com/madneon/147159f46ed478c71d5ee4950a9d697d)

Answer (score 507):

You can use [Django's built-in validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#built-in-validators)—

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Model
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

class CoolModelBro(Model):
    limited_integer_field = IntegerField(
        default=1,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(100),
            MinValueValidator(1)
        ]
     )
```

**Edit**: When working directly with the model, make sure to call the model [full_clean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) method before saving the model in order to trigger the validators. This is not required when using `ModelForm` since the forms will do that automatically.

Comment: I guess you have to write your own validator if you want the limited_integer_field to be optional as well? (Only Validate range if not blank) null=True, blank=True didn't do it..

Comment: In Django 1.7 setting `null=True` and `blank=True` works as expected.  The field is optional and if it's left blank it's stored as null.

Answer (score 106):

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator

size = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0),
                                       MaxValueValidator(5)])
```

Answer (score 57):

I had this very same problem; here was my solution:

```
SCORE_CHOICES = zip( range(1,n), range(1,n) )
score = models.IntegerField(choices=SCORE_CHOICES, blank=True)
```

Comment: Using a list comprehension: `models.IntegerField(choices=[(i, i) for i in range(1, n)], blank=True)`

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways to do this. One is to use form validation to never let any number over 50 be entered by a user. [Form validation docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/).

If there is no user involved in the process, or you're not using a form to enter data, then you'll have to override the model's `save` method to throw an exception or limit the data going into the field.

Comment: You can use a form for validating non-human input, too.  It works great to populate the Form as a all-around validation technique.

Comment: After thinking on this, I'm quite sure I don't want to put the validation in a form. The question of which range of numbers is acceptable is as much a part of the model as is the question of which kind of number is acceptable.

I don't want to have to tell every form through which the model is editable, just which range of numbers to accept. This would violate DRY, and besides, it's just plain inappropriate.

So I'm going to look into overriding the model's save method, or perhaps creating a custom model field type - unless I can find an *even* better way :)

Comment: tghw, you said I could "override the model's save method to throw an exception or limit the data going into the field." How would I - from within the model definition's overriden save() method - make it so that if the number entered is outside a given range, the user receives a validation error much as if she had entered character data into a numeric field? I.e. is there some way I can do this that will work regardless of whether the user is editing via the admin or via some other form? I don't want to just limit the data going into the field without telling the user what's going on :) Thanks!

Comment: Even if you use the "save" method, this wont work when updating table through QuerySet like MyModel.object.filter(blabla).update(blabla) won't call save so no check will be made

Answer (score 5):

Here is the best solution if you want some extra flexibility and don't want to change your model field. Just add this custom validator:

```
#Imports
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError      

class validate_range_or_null(object):
    compare = lambda self, a, b, c: a > c or a < b
    clean = lambda self, x: x
    message = ('Ensure this value is between %(limit_min)s and %(limit_max)s (it is %(show_value)s).')
    code = 'limit_value'

    def __init__(self, limit_min, limit_max):
        self.limit_min = limit_min
        self.limit_max = limit_max

    def __call__(self, value):
        cleaned = self.clean(value)
        params = {'limit_min': self.limit_min, 'limit_max': self.limit_max, 'show_value': cleaned}
        if value:  # make it optional, remove it to make required, or make required on the model
            if self.compare(cleaned, self.limit_min, self.limit_max):
                raise ValidationError(self.message, code=self.code, params=params)
```

And it can be used as such:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):

    ....
    no_dependents = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("How many dependants?", blank=True, null=True, default=0, validators=[validate_range_or_null(1,100)])
```

The two parameters are max and min, and it allows nulls. You can customize the validator if you like by getting rid of the marked if statement or change your field to be blank=False, null=False in the model.  That will of course require a migration.

Note: I had to add the validator because Django does not validate the range on PositiveSmallIntegerField, instead it creates a smallint (in postgres) for this field and you get a DB error if the numeric specified is out of range.

Hope this helps :) More on [Validators in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/validators/).

PS. I based my answer on BaseValidator in django.core.validators, but everything is different except for the code.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can use [MaxValueValidator()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/validators/#maxvaluevalidator) and [MinValueValidator()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/validators/#minvaluevalidator) for [models.DecimalField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) and [models.PositiveIntegerField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield) to set the available range of the value as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

class Test(models.Model):
    num1 = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=3,
        decimal_places=1,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(10.0),
            MinValueValidator(0.0)
        ],
    )
    num2 = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(10),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ],
    )
```

Finally, you better override `num1` and `num2` fields with [forms.DecimalField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/fields/#decimalfield) and [forms.IntegerField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield) to set the available range of the value in Django Admin as shown below:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Test
from django import forms

class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    num1 = forms.DecimalField(
        max_value=10.0, min_value=0.0, step_size=0.1
    )
    num2 = forms.IntegerField(
        max_value=10, min_value=0
    )

@admin.register(Test)
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TestForm
```

In addition, the code with [forms.NumberInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput) below is identical to the code above:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Test
from django import forms

class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    num1 = forms.DecimalField(
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'max': 10.0, 'min': 0.0, 'step': 0.1})
    )
    num2 = forms.IntegerField(
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'max': 10, 'min': 0})
    )

@admin.register(Test)
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TestForm
```

Answer (score 0):

In the forms.py

```
Class FloatForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Float
        fields = ('name','country', 'city', 'point', 'year')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['point'] = forms.FloatField(max_value=100, min_value=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an answer to the question. Since questions often receive multiple answers (this question has seven answers at the moment), it's encouraged to provide some context to your answer to describe why it is different/preferred over other answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning that sometimes Django validation doesn't work as Django validation is mostly an application-level validation, not validation at the database level. Also, Model validation is not run automatically on the save/create/update of the model. If you want to validate your values instantly in your code then you need to do it manually — using the override `save()` method:

```py
class UserRating():
    SCORE_CHOICES = (
        (1, _("Terrible")),
        (2, _("Poor")),
        (3, _("Average")),
        (4, _("Very Good")),
        (5, _("Excellent")),
    )
    score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=SCORE_CHOICES, default=1, 
            validators=[
                MaxValueValidator(5),
                MinValueValidator(1)
            ]
    )
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if int(self.score) < 1 or int(self.score) > 5:
            raise ValidationError('Score must be located between 0 to 5')
        super(UserRating, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add validator like this your model column in models.py

```
class Planogram(models.Model):
    camera = models.ForeignKey(Camera, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    xtl = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=10, max_digits=11,validators=[MaxValueValidator(1),MinValueValidator(0)])
```

if you are using create function to create objects change it to constructor like below....
and call fullclean() on that object and then save..
everything will work perfectly.

```
planogram = Planogram(camera_id = camera,xtl=xtl,ytl=ytl,xbr=xbr,ybr=ybr,product_id=product_id)
planogram.full_clean()
planogram.save()
```