# Django IntegerRangeField Validation failing

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to implement the [IntegerRangeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.IntegerRangeField) for an age range field. Unfortunately the documentation doesn't say how to validate the upper and lower bounds.

I tried it from the model like so:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    age_range = IntegerRangeField(default='(0,100)', blank=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])
```

The problem is, no matter what you put in the field, Django throws a ValidationError:

> The value must be less than or equal to 100

Also if I put nothing in the field, it doesn't put the default range, and fails, complaining about an IntegrityError.

So, I tried doing this from the form object:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    age_range = IntegerRangeField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])
```

But that does nothing at all. Any figure I put in the fields saves. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this and tell me what happens:  
``age_range = IntegerRangeField(lower=1, upper=100, bounds="[]")``
I got it from psycopg2 docs here http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.NumericRange

Comment: the django IntegerRangeField docs mentions that it inherits from the NumericRange field in psycopg2, and don't forget that those are PostgreSQL specific fields, make sure you are using a PostgreSQL db.

Comment: @HassenPy That was actually the first thing I tried in the model. Didn't work. Django wouldn't even migrate, said they were unexpected keywords.

Comment: personally, I wouldn't use a badly documented feature that practically lacks resources on how to implement, try creating a custom field of your own, this might interest you thou http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849142/how-to-limit-the-maximum-value-of-a-numeric-field-in-a-django-model

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `MinValueValidator` and `MaxValueValidator` are for integers, so they are the incorrect validators to use here.  Instead use the validators specifically for ranges: `RangeMinValueValidator` and `RangeMaxValueValidator`.

Both of those validators live in the module `django.contrib.postgres.validators`.

[Here is a link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/validators/) to the validator source code.

Also, an `IntegerRangeField` is represented in Python as a `psycopg2.extras.NumericRange` object, so try using that instead of a string when you specify your `default` parameter in the model.

*Note: The `NumericRange` object by default is inclusive of the lower bound and exclusive of the upper bound, so NumericRange(0, 100) would include 0 and not include 100. You probably want NumericRange(1, 101). You can also specify a `bounds` parameter in your `NumericRange` object to change the defaults for inclusion/exclusion, in lieu of changing the number values.  See [the NumericRange object documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.NumericRange).*

Example:

```
# models.py file
from django.contrib.postgres.validators import RangeMinValueValidator, RangeMaxValueValidator
from psycopg2.extras import NumericRange

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    age_range = IntegerRangeField(
        default=NumericRange(1, 101),
        blank=True,
        validators=[
            RangeMinValueValidator(1), 
            RangeMaxValueValidator(100)
        ]
    )
```

Comment: This worked! I looked through all the contrib.postgres files but must have missed this. Thanks. The NumericRange note was helpful too, though it seemed my previous method also worked.