# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IntegerRangeField'

Tags: python, django

I got an error,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IntegerRangeField'   .
I wrote in models.py

```
class ImageAndUser(models.Model):
rbc = models.IntegerRangeField(min_value=1, max_value=100)
```

I think maybe something to be needed is not imported in models.py,
but it is not true.
How can I fix this?

Comment: IntegerRangeField is not a standard django field (See model field reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/). Where did you get this code from?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460309/django-integerrangefield-validation-failing

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know django.db.models doesn't have implementation of IntegerRangeField.

Try tu use [django.contrib.postgres.fields.ranges.IntegerRangeField](https://fossies.org/dox/Django-1.10.5/classdjango_1_1contrib_1_1postgres_1_1fields_1_1ranges_1_1IntegerRangeField.html) or [django IntegerRangeField snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/3016/).

Comment: I added your django IntegerRangeField snippet in my model,
but I got same error,AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IntegerRangeField'.What should I do?

Comment: Try `rbc = IntegerRangeField(min_value=1, max_value=100)` instead of `rbc = models.IntegerRangeField(min_value=1, max_value=100)`

Comment: thx, but i got same error although i use ur new code.what should i do?