# Django restrict input in the admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm wondering how can I retrict the input of a field in the admin to only numbers and a max of 10 digits. The "max of 10 digits" part is confusing.

The model field is this one:

```
id_student = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

How can I make sure that in the admin it gets a max of 10 digits? I'm kind of lost in the docs and imagining weird ways to achieve this, I bet there is a simple way.

**EDIT**

Tried adding `max_length=10`, doesn't work:

```
id_student = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok what I did that worked was using from `django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator`:

```
id_student = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999999999)])
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think `max_length=10` should do the trick for you.

Comment: What happens when you try to enter more than 10 digits in the admin after using this?

Answer (score 1):

You may find the answer here:
[How to limit the maximum value of a numeric field in a Django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849142/how-to-limit-the-maximum-value-of-a-numeric-field-in-a-django-model)