# How to specify maximum value for model decimal field django?

Tags: python, django, forms, model, widget

I am trying to make price field that has a maximum value. But I have seen that it is not possible to specify max value in models decimal field. Therefor I created a form decimal field which takes max value attribute but if do that I am not able to use the model's price field's properties.
In models.py

```
 price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

In forms.py

```
 price = forms.DecimalField(max_value=500)
```

I know I can just write all of them in forms and leave the blank and null in model's decimal field but doing that is redundant as I have many other fields.

Is there a way I can use the model's decimal field and still specify the max length and min length for that field through forms class.

Comment: Check this out:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849142/how-to-limit-the-maximum-value-of-a-numeric-field-in-a-django-model][1]

Comment: max_value can be used in forms as of now. So you can give an error message when the value exceeds. I did not understand this `if do that I am not able to use the model's price field's properties`. Can you share your forms.