# How to set max for positiveintegerfield

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am writing a model in django. I want to set a maximum number for a positiveintegerfield. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit the maximum value of a numeric field in a Django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/849142/1165509)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:
`models.PositiveIntegerField(min_value=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(100),])`

More info in the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/#maxvaluevalidator