# How to set up a maximum value in a Django DurationField?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a Django models with a DurationField. I would like that the users cannot put a value over 00:09:59. Unfortunately I could not find any information to do this in the doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#durationfield

Comment: you can create value validator. checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12026867/16250404)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add validators for that.

It will look something like:

```
DurationField(
    validators=[MaxValueValidator(datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)]
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with default `DurationField`.

You can override the `clean_%s` method in the form:

```py
from django import forms


class YourForm(forms.Form):
    duration_field = forms.DurationField()

    def clean_duration_field(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['duration_field']
        if value > timedelta(minutes=9, seconds=59):
            raise forms.ValidationError("....", code="invalid")
        
        return data
```

If you need to do this validation in many places, you can create a custom Field for overriding the validating method of field:

```py
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import validate_email

class RestrictedDurationField(forms.DurationField):

    def __init__(self, limit: timdelta, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.limit = limit

    def validate(self, value):
        super().validate(value)
        if value > self.limit:
            raise forms.ValidationError("....", code="invalid")


# and usage
class form(Form):
    duration_field = RestrictedDurationField(limit=timedelta(minutes=9, seconds=59), ...)
```